# React, conditional rendering inside map method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have the following code and I want to apply a conditional rendering, because the index 0 does not exist. I don't want to render the information for this particular index. How can I do it?

```
return (
        <section>
            {pokemonCards.map((pokemon, index) =>             
                <div key={index}>
                <img 
                    src={`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${index}.png`} 
                    alt={pokemon.name}/>
                <p>{pokemon.name}</p>
                </div>
            )}
            <button 
                className="get-more-button" 
                onClick={getMorePokemons}>Get more pokemons
            </button>
        </section>
    )
```

Comment: Why don't you apply a pokemonCards.shift() before using that array ? It will remove the first element. You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

Comment: Thanks! Where exactly this method would be written in the code? inside the return?

Comment: Before the return, so the array is modified when you use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
return (
        <section>
            {pokemonCards.map((pokemon, index) =>             
                {index === 0 ? null : <div key={index}>
                <img 
                    src={`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${index}.png`} 
                    alt={pokemon.name}/>
                <p>{pokemon.name}</p>
                </div>
            )}
            <button 
                className="get-more-button" 
                onClick={getMorePokemons}>Get more pokemons
            </button>}
        </section>
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do as below if you do not want to render an empty `div` for the nonexisting pokemon:

```
 return (
    <section>
      {pokemonCards.map(
        (pokemon, index) =>
          index !== 0 && (
            <div key={index}>
              <img
                src={`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${index}.png`}
                alt={pokemon.name}
              />
              <p>{pokemon.name}</p>
            </div>
          )
      )}
      <button className="get-more-button" onClick={getMorePokemons}>
        Get more pokemons
      </button>
    </section>
  );
```

Comment: Should we not to add the index as a key?